# Unwanted behavior: This database is attempting to establish a connection with a remote SQL server, click yes to proceed

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I noticed this new behaviour in my ms access frontend:

> This database is attempting to establish a connection with a remote SQL server, click yes to proceed

This message box is not coded by me. it is opened automatically.

**(1) Originally, my application is setup like this:**

On startup, I open a form via application options:
[image]

This form runs some code and then opens the mainpage form via docmd.openform "mainpage".
Then I get this error:

[image]

The interesting thing is, that "mainpage" does not have Form_open event. I believe it is cancelled by the same mechanism that opens the msgbox as seen in the first picture. With this setup, the message box is not shown.

**(2) for debugging, I changed the setup to this:**
In the application options, I set the form "mainpage" to be displayed on startup. Not opening form "Initialize" at all. Then I get the message box as seen in the first picture.

**Question**
How do I fix this? Where does this new behaviour  come from?
How do I prevent the error on docmd.openform "mainpage" and/or suppress the display of this message box?

Comment: Do you have [linked tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-linked-tables-1d9346d6-953d-4f85-a9ce-4caec2262797)?

Comment: yes I do have linked tables.

Comment: Do they link to an SQL Server?

Comment: This seems to be a newly introduced "feature" in Access, not caused by your code. It has been reported to Microsoft for clarification.

Comment: @GSerg yes they link to SQL Server :)

Comment: @Gustav do you know where I can find an overview / Explanation of the features and which update exactly it was?

Comment: Can I ask, whether you get the OpenForm error message regardless of whether you select Yes or No in the connection prompt? Or do you only get the error if you select No in the prompt? Thanks

Comment: @TheSmileyCoder the OpenForm Error message only appears when the form is opened via DoCmd.OpenForm. And the connection prompt only appears when the main form is used as first display form in the application options. So it has nothing to do with what I select in the prompt. 

I hope this is understandable. Sorry for the complicated description. It is a bit complicated.

Comment: This warning will not be included in the next Current Channel release.
Microsoft is looking at the feedback. More to follow, I guess.

Comment: @Simorgh Its my understanding that the prompt is intended to be shown when the first connection attempt to a remote server is initiated by CODE or by Startup (autoexec/display form). If the user manually clicks then it shouldn't happen. I don't have Insiders myself, so can't say for sure. 
Its very disappointing if you get the error even after accepting the connection in the prompt.

Comment: "Its very disappointing if you get the error even after accepting the connection in the prompt." - The error did not come after the prompt!